# What's FreeBSD uthread?

Tags: multithreading, freebsd

I heard there is a user land thread library in FreeBSD named `unthread`. But I can't find any information about this. What is this? And where can I find manual for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://unobvious.com/bsd/freebsd-threads.html):

> Documentation for FreeBSD's native threads is available via the pthread(3) man page.

```
man pthread
```

Web link is [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pthread&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports).